# Frequency of the surge voltage

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, over-voltage-protection

When analyzing an electrical circuit, and in the occurrence of an impedance mismatch between the supply voltage and the load (connected through a cable) + a high switching frequency, reflection phenomena take place and surges are noticed. What is the frequency of the surge voltage?

Comment: Surges are inherently broadband. So, it doesn't have a single frequency.

Comment: You are right. What about the fundamental ?

Comment: broadband signals don't have a fundamental. They're broadband. There's no such thing as a "pseudo-frequency". It's really not clear what you're asking here? And why?

Comment: Broadband meaning they have a harmonically rich spectrum right

Comment: Because I have a surge in my voltages and I would like to know what is its frequency(or pseudo-frequency). I might as well just apply an fft and see I guess. Just thought of that.

Comment: no, it doesn't mean they have a "harmonically rich spectrum". They're broadband. "Pseudo-frequency" is still not a word, as far as I'm concerned. Why are you assuming there's discrete frequencies in them? They're surges. Do a continuous-time fourier transform on an impulse – that gives you a constant all over the spectrum. Your surge isn't a mathematically perfect impulse, but it's close.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I don't know why I was assuming they have discrete frequencies in them. Thank you so much for enlightening me Marcus!

Comment: Do note that if your switching happens strictly periodically, you *do* get discrete lines in the spectrum ("spurs") in your spectrum; but switch-mode power supplies necessarily "modulate" the amplitude of your surges load-dependently, so you don't get a "clean" line spectrum (even if you observed forever). In fact, some switch-mode power supplies don't have fixed periods.

Comment: Yes, I have a period switching

Comment: Well, then you get spurs with wideband "skirts". You get the worst of both worlds, congratulations!